# A difference between the conjunctions "why" and "when"

Tags: word-usage

I think **both** the following sentences are correct:

> A. The reason **that** I asked the question is that I am interested in the subject.

> B. The reason **why** I asked the question is that I am interested in the subject.

But **only** statement A among the following two sentences is correct:

> A. The last time **that** I saw him, he was tired.

> B. The last time **when** I saw him, he was tired.

Am I right with the above evaluations? If so, why are "when" and "why" subject to different grammatical rules?

Comment: One explanation I can think of myself is the following. The second pair includes the adjective "last" and that is the main reason for the difference. If we add a similar adjective to the word "reason" in the first sentence, then only the case with "that" will be acceptable even in the first pair.

Comment: I think you're onto something, with that comment, HD. _The time when I saw him_ is fine.

Comment: @ColinFine Thank you for this! I appreciate it! I wonder how natural the following sentences sound to you: "The most important reason why I asked the question is blah blah" or "The major reason why I asked the question is blah blah". I am trying to test the other side of my hypothesis. That is, the presence of an adjective before the word "reason" makes the conjunction "why" unacceptable.

Comment: No, they sound OK to me. (Mind you, my father objected to _the reason why_ in any context: he thought it was redundant).

Comment: Got it. Thank you for all your help! I appreciate it!

Comment: I think that your premise is flawed. For example, consider [this sentence](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Computer_Networks_and_Systems_Queueing_T/uRcDCAAAQBAJ?gbpv=1&dq=%22the+last+time+when%22&pg=PA26): "That is, you can't predict when you'll flip heads by knowing the last time when heads occurred."

Comment: @MarcInManhattan Thank you for your help! I really appreciate it. As you alluded to, [Google books](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22the+last+time+when%22&tbm=bks&ei=1q86Yr7IMOC_0PEP0tSyQA&start=10&sa=N&ved=2ahUKEwi-i93sv9v2AhXgHzQIHVKqDAgQ8NMDegQIARBQ&biw=1536&bih=754&dpr=1.25) suggests the phrase "the last time when" does occur in the real world. 

But, it seems like the examples typically fall under one of the following two categories: (i) Relatively old texts (Late 1800s, early 1900s) (ii) Technical texts. But anyway, they do occur.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least in spoken American English, all four examples are permissible. In the last example, which you think is a problem, you could also say:

**When I saw him the last time, he was tired.**

and that would be fine, too.

Comment: Thank you for the tips!